# How trace exception JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, xpages, ssjs

I developed an XPages application with access Anonymous that querying real-time inventories.
Everything works perfectly
So I've created OSGI package with the driver [JTOpen](http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) to access DB2 AS400 (iSeries) database
When you open the page, everything goes perfectly.
The problem show when there are a user inactivit (iconize the windows browsers and reopen the xpages)

I used different editbox, combox that executing SQL queries in partial refresh mode to filter and search DB2 Iseries.

My problem is that after several minutes of inactivity, I noted that the combox no longer work and it seems that the fall JDBC connection 
(I have activate the keepalive feature for the Ping)

... but I do not know how I can debug this possible JDBC exception.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is my as40.jdbc file under WebContent-->WEB-INF-->jdbc

```
<jdbc type="simple">
    <driver>com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:as400://192.168.X.X;naming=system;errors=full</url>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pwd</password>

<simple>
    <minPoolSize>10</minPoolSize>
    <maxPoolSize>20</maxPoolSize>
    <maxConnectionSize>200</maxConnectionSize>
    <useTimeout>1</useTimeout>
    <idleTimeout>00</idleTimeout>
    <maxLiveTime>00</maxLiveTime>
    <acquireTimeout>10000</acquireTimeout>
</simple>       
</jdbc>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a timeout setting in the url you can specify.

jdbc:as400://xxx.com;libraries=libs;sort=hex;socket timeout=30000;thread used=false;translate binary=true;prompt=false;

Perhaps the issue is with your code on the XPage? How do you bind the values in the combobox to the jdbc data?

Howard

Comment: the combox is only a filter...
that execute a partial refresh where the target is a repeat control that bind the JDBC Object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of having `useTimeout=1`. I believe that will mean connections are removed that have been in use for more than 1 second. You could try setting `useTimeout=0` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Ok I try this solution and update this post after. tnx